# Given the tetrahedron $OABC$, find a condition on $a OA+ b OB + c OC$ such that this is always inside $ABC$.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I did the following:

Taking the tetrahedron $OABC$, one can decompose it in: $OA,OB,OC, AB,BC$. And then, writing:

$$x(BC-AB)+AB\quad x\in[0,1]$$

We obtain all the points in the line segment from $AB$ to $BC$. Now if we multiply it by another scalar $y$, we have:

$$y(x(BC-AB)+AB)\quad x,y\in[0,1]$$

This would give me all the points inside $ABC$. The condition would be that:

$$y(x(BC-AB)+AB)= \lambda OA + \zeta OB + \psi OC$$

Writing:

$$BC=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\quad AB=(a_4,a_5,a_6) \quad OA=(a_7,a_8,a_9)\\ OB=(a_{10},a_{11},a_{12}) \quad OC=(a_{13},a_{14},a_{15})$$

We have:

\begin{bmatrix}
 -a_{10} \zeta -a_7 \lambda +a_1 x y+a_4 (y-x y)-a_{13} \psi =0  \\
 -a_{11} \zeta -a_8 \lambda +a_2 x y+a_5 (y-x y)-a_{14} \psi =0 \\
 -a_{12} \zeta -a_9 \lambda +a_3 x y+a_6 (y-x y)-a_{15} \psi =0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

With $x,y \in [0,1]$.

I have actually two questions:

1. Is there a simpler way?
2. Is it possible to answer it the way I'm doing? I guess that there is some kind of matrix property that could be used to show the conditions on $\zeta, \lambda, \psi$. Perhaps determinants?

Comment: I think the condition put in a simpler way is $a + b + c = 1$.

Comment: @corindo Thanks. But why is that condition true? I've been trying to prove it but have no success until now.